# The urlpatterns generated by Django vs their official page

Tags: python, django

In the official documentations of Django, the urlpatters have an incipit of "path"

The Django generated urls.py, it has an incipit of "url".

This makes it hard for me to follow tutorials, could you tell me how this is possible? I'm having problems making urlpatters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your django version is 1.11 or bellow while ,the docs are for django 2 and above

you can use pip freeze to check your django version and then in djago doc urls : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ <--------- change the 2.0 to the django version you have and you'll get the correct doc

Comment: Or, use the docs for the version you have. They're well signposted from every page.

Comment: Thank you for explaining. This helps me a lot!